# How to always bring a window to the front with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

Here is a link in my page (MAIN) :

```
<a href="log_details.jsf#MyAnchor" target="log">View details</a>
```

If no window is alredy opened, a new one appears (let's call it LOG) and is bringed on top pointing at the anchor.

If LOG stays opened and user decides to go back to MAIN for clicking on another link like this

```
<a href="log_details.jsf#MyAnchor2" target="log">View details</a>
```

The position in LOG is moved to MyAnchor2 but LOG is not bringed to top.

How can I make LOG appears on top any time the user click on a link similar to :

```
<a href="log_details.jsf#MyAnchorXXX" target="log">View details</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the window is already open and is known by the variable `log` in your Javascript, you should be able to call `log.focus()` on the window to bring it to the front.

**Edit:**

When you use the `target` attribute, it give the window a 'name'. This name is separate from Javascript variables, though. So in the instance where `target="log"`, there is no corresponding variable named `log` to reference with the `.focus()` function.

```
function logLinks(){
    //Get every A tag
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    //Iterate through the elements and...
    for(i=0; i<links.length; i++){
        //If the element has a class of 'log'
        if(links[i].className=='log'){
            //Clone it
            var dup = links[i].cloneNode(true);
            //Strip move the href elsewhere
            dup.id=dup.href; 
            dup.href='';
            //Add a click listener
            dup.addEventListener('click', function(){openLog(this.id);}, false);
            //Replace the existing element on the page
            links[i].parentNode.replaceChild(dup, links[i]);
        }
    }
}

function openLog(link){
    //Open a window and give it focus
    var wh = window.open(link, 'logWindow');
    wh.focus();
}

//Run this function on page load
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", logLinks);
```

The above code will go through the page and replace any `a` tags that are set to have the `log` class with a version that opens a window to the relevant `href` of that link and then does `focus` on the resulting window.

Comment: @Stephan Did you put `class="log"` on the links?

Comment: The first time I click, the window appears to front. If I come back to main window and I click on another link, the log window updates its content but doesn't come back to front :\